# VBA GetObject from Multiple Open Instances of Attachmate Reflection?

Tags: excel, vba, attachmate-reflection

My company recently upgraded from Attachmate EXTRA! to Attachmate Reflection. We have a number of macros that ran on extra to screen scrape. Basically, you would press a button to start the macro, it would ask you to select which extra screen you wanted to run it on (we always have 3+ open for different systems), and then the macro would just use the most recently selected (active) session. Here's the code for that:

```
Private Function GetReflectionWindow(sessionName As String) As ExtraScreen
'Gets the most recent active reflection or extra window.
'Requires Reference: EXTRACOM

    Dim sys As ExtraSystem: Set sys = CreateObject("EXTRA.System")
    Dim sess As ExtraSession

    'Set current sesion to most recently active session
    If MsgBox("Click on the " & sessionName & " session and click 'OK' to continue.", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then End

    Set sess = sys.ActiveSession

    'Checks the session
    If sess Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not locate a Reflection or Extra session!", vbCritical
        End
    Else
        Set GetReflectionWindow = sess.Screen
        sess.Activate
    End If

End Function
```

This no longer works for Reflection systems. Instead I've looked at this documentation [here](http://docs.attachmate.com/reflection/16-2/vba-prog-guide/create-session-from-another-application.html). The problem is that when you use CreateObject or GetObject, it only looks at the first open instance, not the active instance.

```
Sub GetNewReflectionWindow()

    Dim App As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Framework.ApplicationObject
    Dim screen As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Emulation_IbmHosts.IbmScreen
    Dim Terminal As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Emulation_IbmHosts.IbmTerminal
    Dim Frame As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects.Frame
    Dim View As Attachmate_Reflection_Objects.View


    Set App = GetObject(, "Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Framework.ApplicationObject")

End Sub
```

I can't see anything in the documentation or object browser that would let me select the active session like Extra.System did.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and finally found the solution in the MicroFocus docs of all places! [Accessing All Open "Reflection Workspace" Objects in VBA Macro Code](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7022995)

Basically, continue to use CreateObject to get the Workspace, but do it in a loop renaming each one as you go:

```
    Dim oSession As Object
    'find all open sessions
    Do
        Set oSession = CreateObject("Reflection Workspace")
        oActiveSession.AutomationServerName = "Unused"
    Loop

    'rename sessions back to original
    Do
        Set oActiveSession = CreateObject("Unused")
        oActiveSession.AutomationServerName = "Reflection Workspace"
    Loop
```

I put this into its own function as the CreateObject throws an error when you run out of Workspaces.